# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context. <SocketEngine> Class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, swift4

I am using Xcode 9 and Swift 4.

I have a project which is written in Swift 3 and Xcode 8.

I was trying to run this code in Xcode 9. After Xcode converted Swift 3 to Swift 4, I came across the following error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

[Here is the link from where I was using the Swift file.](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/blob/master/Source/SocketIO/Engine/SocketEngine.swift)

The error is in the following method:

```
private func handleBase64(message: String) {
    // binary in base64 string
    let noPrefix = message[message.index(message.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)..<message.endIndex]

    if let data = NSData(base64Encoded: noPrefix, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
        client?.parseEngineBinaryData(data as Data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **should not update** the library's functions to Swift 4 manually.

Download the library again, [it has now been updated to Swift 4](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/releases/tag/v12.0.0).

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help. Let's give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
if let data = Data(base64Encoded: noPrefix, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
            client?.parseEngineBinaryData(data)
        }
```

To :::::

```
if let data = Data(base64Encoded: **String(noPrefix)**, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
            client?.parseEngineBinaryData(data)
        }
```